# TTS reading error for thai words

Tags: text-to-speech, google-translate

when TTS reads sentence
1.  "กลอนอกหักน้อยใจ ก็แค่คนหนึ่งคน" In the last word,it supposed to read "Khon" but it reads "Ko-no".

2. "วันนี้ฝนตก." It reads wan nee phon tor kor" It should be "wan nee phon tok".

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. What is your question here? Have a look on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can help improve Google Translate for the languages you speak [here](https://translate.google.com/intl/en_ALL/about/languages/th).